# Client side programming

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

Do you know any good book on 2015 that combines both angular 2 and react ?  Is there any free online course on corsera ? Lecture ? I would like to understand both so I can choose between them

I know it's just a beta for angular 2 but it mostly for learning .

If it exist I would also like to learn web components .

Answer (score 2):

https://egghead.io/ features great video series on React, Angular and lots of other front-end stuff. Some are restricted to a Premium access though.